# Mapping array in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm developing a small application in `VueJS 2.0` where I'm having a data set something like this:

```
{"data":
    [
        {
            "id":8,
            "salutation":"Mr",
            "first_name":"Madhu",
            "last_name":"Kela",
            "number":"2343253455",
            "mobile":"3252345435",
            "email":"madhu@reliancemf.com",
            "alt_email":null,
            "address":"Mumbai BKC",
            "city":"Mumbai",
            "state":null,
            "country":"India",
            "profile":null,
            "sectors_interested":"[\"Insurance\",\"Infrastructure\",\"Information Technology\",\"hevy machines\",\"Healtcare\"]",
            "companies_interested":"[4]",
            "interactions_count":11,
            "client_interactions_count":0,
            "company":[
                {
                    "id":7,
                    "name":"Reliance MF",
                    "address":"Mumbai BKC",
                    "city":"Mumbai",
                    "state":null,
                    "country":"India",
                    "type":"Investor",
                    "sub_type":"Mutual Fund",
                    "is_client":0,
                    "pivot":{
                        "contact_id":8,
                        "company_id":7,
                        "created_at":"2017-07-01 17:07:08",
                        "updated_at":"2017-07-01 17:07:08"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":7,
            "salutation":"Ms",
            "first_name":"XYZ",
            "last_name":"ABC",
            "number":"1847171087",
            "mobile":"8327523057",
            "email":"skbkjgerbra@dabflvdjf.com",
            "alt_email":null,
            "address":"Mumbai",
            "city":"Mumbai",
            "state":null,
            "country":"India",
            "profile":null,
            "sectors_interested":"[\"Insurance\",\"Information Technology\",\"Infrastructure\",\"hevy machines\"]",
            "companies_interested":"[6,4]",
            "interactions_count":8,
            "client_interactions_count":0,
            "company":[
                {
                    "id":3,
                    "name":"Franklin Fun",
                    "address":"Mumbai",
                    "city":"Mumbai",
                    "state":null,
                    "country":"India",
                    "type":"Investor",
                    "sub_type":"Mutual Fund",
                    "is_client":0,
                    "pivot":{
                        "contact_id":7,
                        "company_id":3,
                        "created_at":"2017-07-01 16:59:41",
                        "updated_at":"2017-07-01 16:59:41"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want map these values something like this:

```
return this.model.map(d => ({
    name: d.first_name + ' ' +d.last_name,
    company: d.company[0].name,
    email: d.email,
    mobile: d.mobile,
    profile: d.profile,
    count: d.interactions_count ? d.interactions_count : d.client_interactions_count
}))
```

Also as you see in the code I want to place `interactions_count` by comparing i.e. if `interactions_count` is 0 I want to map with `client_interactions_count`, I'm unable to get company name from the first array parameter, and order it with the `count` in descending order whatever it comes by response. Help me out in this. Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure the variable names in your code examples match.


Also, have you tried to just dump `d`? You will see if maybe the company name is undefined.

Comment: Dont you have to do `this.modal.data`, 'cause this object is in "model" variable, you still have `data` there.

Comment: @FranzSkuffka yes it is.

Comment: If it is undefined, the problem is not within your map lambda.

Comment: @yev yes while placing it in model through response I'm doing something like this. `this.model = response.data.data`

Comment: Please give us more code. This is poking in the dark.

Comment: @FranzSkuffka it is not throwing `undefined` and what do you need?

Comment: If you want us to debug your app we need the entire chain from HTTP request to your mapping function.

You really should try to figure out the problem yourself using the chrome inspector (network tab, js debugger).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id":8,
        "salutation":"Mr",
        "first_name":"Madhu",
        "last_name":"Kela",
        "number":"2343253455",
        "mobile":"3252345435",
        "email":"madhu@reliancemf.com",
        "alt_email":null,
        "address":"Mumbai BKC",
        "city":"Mumbai",
        "state":null,
        "country":"India",
        "profile":null,
        "sectors_interested":"[\"Insurance\",\"Infrastructure\",\"Information Technology\",\"hevy machines\",\"Healtcare\"]",
        "companies_interested":"[4]",
        "interactions_count":11,
        "client_interactions_count":0,
        "company":[
            {
                "id":7,
                "name":"Reliance MF",
                "address":"Mumbai BKC",
                "city":"Mumbai",
                "state":null,
                "country":"India",
                "type":"Investor",
                "sub_type":"Mutual Fund",
                "is_client":0,
                "pivot":{
                    "contact_id":8,
                    "company_id":7,
                    "created_at":"2017-07-01 17:07:08",
                    "updated_at":"2017-07-01 17:07:08"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":7,
        "salutation":"Ms",
        "first_name":"XYZ",
        "last_name":"ABC",
        "number":"1847171087",
        "mobile":"8327523057",
        "email":"skbkjgerbra@dabflvdjf.com",
        "alt_email":null,
        "address":"Mumbai",
        "city":"Mumbai",
        "state":null,
        "country":"India",
        "profile":null,
        "sectors_interested":"[\"Insurance\",\"Information Technology\",\"Infrastructure\",\"hevy machines\"]",
        "companies_interested":"[6,4]",
        "interactions_count":8,
        "client_interactions_count":0,
        "company":[
            {
                "id":3,
                "name":"Franklin Fun",
                "address":"Mumbai",
                "city":"Mumbai",
                "state":null,
                "country":"India",
                "type":"Investor",
                "sub_type":"Mutual Fund",
                "is_client":0,
                "pivot":{
                    "contact_id":7,
                    "company_id":3,
                    "created_at":"2017-07-01 16:59:41",
                    "updated_at":"2017-07-01 16:59:41"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

const result = data.map((item) => {
  return {
    name: item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name,
    company: item.company[0].name,
    email: item.email,
    mobile: item.mobile,
    profile: item.profile,
    count: item.interactions_count ? item.interactions_count : item.client_interactions_count
  };
}).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count); 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there any way to sort this with `count` values in descending order?